# Motivation behind proof of structure theorem for PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, proof-explanation

I was reading the below proof in D&Fs Abstract Algebra, pg 460. I understand every step of the proof, but I have trouble motivating myself of how the authors came up with the first step.

***Why* they took the maximal element from $$\Sigma:= \{ ( a_\phi) \,: \, \phi  \in Hom_R(M,R) \}$$ and *why they knew* defining $\Sigma$ would yield an element $y_1$ that gives a direct sum. What was the intuition/theory behind?**

(Beginning of proof below)

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the strong impression that this proof is an improvement of the [Smith normal form algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Algorithm) avoiding constructs involving gcd e.a., but only the framework of a PID ring. In this context $\Sigma$ stands for the matrix columns (rows?) defining the sublattice $N$.